# Ruby On Rails update_all test not equal in conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-all

I'm trying to update some min and max fields so that is one is left empty then the value is copied form the other. So far I have:

`Item.update_all({:min = :max}, {:min => nil, :max !=> nil})`

Since both fields could be `nil` I have whether they are but the `!=>` isn't correct. How would I go about testing for not equal to using this style of condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not valid ruby syntax for hashes.

Try:

```
Item.update_all("min = max", "min IS NULL AND max IS NOT NULL")
```

Or alternatively:

```
Item.where("min IS NULL AND max IS NOT NULL").update_all("min = max")
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to either of these or do they produce the same SQL?

Comment: They produce exactly the same query. My personal preference is for the second option since it is more readable and allows the use of scopes. For example `scope has_only_max, lambda { where("min IS NULL AND max IS NOT NULL")}` 
Then you can do: `Item.has_only_max.update_all("min = max")